# I wanted to add a way to store points earned between games (Java)

Tags: java, jpanel

I had several attempts of using java.io in several ways, but I could never get it to work. My idea was to store points earned in a file named save_data.txt, then retrieve the 3 highest integers in that list and display them on a leaderboard.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextFind {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
File file = new File("save_data.txt");
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;

    while((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(text));
    }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    try {
        if(reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {     
    }
}

}
}
```

I took this and called it when the game stopped running. It seems to do nothing.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: @user1803551 This particular code isn't having issues, though, which that article seems to be addressing. As I said, I ommited the code that was causing issues because I felt like I wasn't going anywhere with it.

Comment: You want to store data in a file and read it? Post your attempt. What are we supposed to do with the code you posted?

Comment: @user1803551 The code I posted was mainly for help formatting what I'm supposed to do. I wouldn't know the correct method to put it in, as I'm new to Java.

Comment: What *are* you supposed to do? The code you posted does business logic - painting, user interaction, collision checking etc. Is this related to your problem?

Comment: @user1803551 The code I posted is Snake. It works fine (barring a few performance issues I'm slowly working on). I have a point counter that keeps a tally of how much food the player has eaten. I wanted to save the points earned in a seperate file to display high scores/leaderboards.

Comment: "*I wanted to save the points earned in a seperate file to display high scores/leaderboards.*" Then post your attempt at doing that instead of the game logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not that far off actually. Are there values in your save_date.txt file? Here is some example using Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> highScore = Arrays.asList(1, 2); // Dummy values
    Path filePath = Paths.get("save_data.txt"); // Your saved data

    // Transform available high scores to a single String using the System line separator to separated the values and afterwards transform the String to bytes ...
    byte[] bytes = highScore.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())).getBytes();

    try {
        // Write those high score bytes to a file ...
        Files.write(filePath, bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
    try {
        // Read all available high scores lines from the file ...
        lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int skipLines = Math.max(lines.size() - 3, 0); // You only want the three highest values so we use the line count to determine the amount of values that may be skipped and we make sure that the value may not be negative...

    // Stream through all available lines stored in the file, transform the String objects to Integer objects,  sort them, skip all values except the last three and sort their order descending
    highScore = lines.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).sorted().skip(skipLines).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Print the result
    highScore.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: I had 4 dummy values in the file originally, but when I played the game and got a few scores, nothing was added.

Comment: In your example above you only read available values, but you still need to write new values to the file. You should take a look at [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) or [Files#write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) like in my example.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Just completely forgot to add anything like that. Thanks!

Comment: @jlars789 See how easy it is with a MCVE?

Comment: @user1803551 Yeah I gotta do that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen the List<Integer> thing before but it always says it doesn't work. It says it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>

Comment: Which Java version are you using?